# Cannot distinguish between up/down arrow in stdin raw mode

Tags: node.js, stdin

I have this bit of code:

```
  process.stdin.setRawMode(true).resume();

  process.stdin.on('data', (buf) => {

    const str = String(buf);
    const charAsAscii = String(buf.toString().charCodeAt(0));

    switch (charAsAscii) {

      case '25': // left arrow ?
        console.log('left arrow');
        return;

      case '26': // right arrow ?
        console.log('right arrow');
        return;

      case '27': // down arrow
        console.log('down arrow');
        return;

      case '28': // up arrow?
        console.log('up arrow');
        return;

      default:
        console.error('default')
    }

}
```

all the arrow keys seem to be recognized as up arrow, that is, **all 4 arrow keys always match case '28'** ... I am looking to distinguish between up/down/left/right arrow keys, anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you print out the "charAsAscii" variable before going into the switch, is it producing expected values? (I'm not a node person at all, so sorry if it's a dumb clarification to ask for)

Comment: let me check hold on, not a dumb question

Comment: yeah as I described in the OP, it's always code '27' no matter which of the 4 arrow keys I hit, I am on MacOS right now btw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to capture the arrow keys in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17470554/how-to-capture-the-arrow-keys-in-node-js)

Comment: The buffer you get from stdin contains typed characters, but arrow keys are not characters. They and other such things are encoded as escape sequences. For example, the sequence 1B 5B 41 is the "up" arrow. All you get with `.charCodeAt(0)` is the ASCII escape character (0x1B = 27) that introduces that escape sequence.

Comment: hmmm thx I dont know a lot about this, can you add an answer explaining more exactly how to capture each arrow key?

Comment: I've linked a dupe?

Comment: yeah that works I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrow keys, buffer is a bit different : there are 3 bytes.
I have no idea what they represent, but i just know you have to get the third char :

```
process.stdin.setRawMode(true)
process.stdin.on('data', (data) => {
    const str = data.toString();
    if (str.length == 3) {
        console.log(str.charCodeAt(2))
    }
})
```

Arrow codes :

Up -> 65
Down -> 66
Right -> 67
Left -> 68